# Flatpak run external programs

Tags: godot, flatpak

I am using a flatpak version of my favorite game engine, godot. Using it, I need to be able to export to android. To do this, it needs adb.

I tried looking in /usr/bin, where the adb executable is located, but Godot couldn't see it because of the flatpak's sandboxing.

I tried runing the flatpack with the --filesystem option, but it didn't work.

Does anyone know how to get the flatpak to have access to the whole filesystem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [know issue](https://github.com/flathub/org.godotengine.Godot/issues/15). Snap package has issues too. The best option is to use the official executable from the website. If want auto updates you can use Steam or Itch.io